# hp 2920 stack hot swap

Tags: networking, hp, hp-procurve, aruba

I have 4x HP/Aruba 2920s configured in a stack using the dedicated stack hardware and cabling.  All seems to be working well except for one issue:

On the first unit which is acting as the "commander", the 4x dual personality ports work for both copper and gbic.  On the remaining 3x units in the stack, the gbic slots do not work.

Inserting a working gbic module into the slot shows no information in the event log - no indication of insertion, failed module, or any entry at all.

Any idea why the gbic slots aren't working on these other units?